# Multiple toMany relationships to a single table

Tags: android, orm, relational-database, greendao

I'm new to [greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/) and I'm working on writing the DaoGenerator. One issue that I've run into is that I have a user table and a wallpost table. I would like to be able to have two columns in the wallpost table that are toMany relations to the user table (the wall owner and the posting user) they may or may not be the same user, but so far it doesn't look like it is possible to have two toMany relations that point to a single table in the same table.

Is there a better way to do this/a way to make this possible? I'm hoping to be able to load the wall posts and fetch the wall owner and posting user by calling .getOwner() and .getPoster().

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must set names for the relations. Have a look at the (just improved) section called [Relation Names and multiple Relations](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/relations/) of the documentation on relations. It comes with an example:

```
Property pictureIdProperty = user.addLongProperty("pictureId").getProperty();
Property thumbnailIdProperty = user.addLongProperty("thumbnailId").getProperty();
user.addToOne(picture, pictureIdProperty);
user.addToOne(picture, thumbnailIdProperty, "thumbnail");
```